# Can one access data generated in a Wi-Fi network from the modem?

Tags: security, wireless-router, lan, isp

I find this question is best phrased with a scenario, so here goes nothing.

**Scenario**

**Tom** owns a modem and a router, and gets internet service from Comcast. Tom uses his router to broadcast his own Wi-Fi network.  Tom's modem does not have an integrated router.  Tom connects his modem to an ethernet switch, and then connects his router to that switch.

Tom's neighbor, **George**, owns a router. George also uses his router to broadcast a Wi-Fi network, with a different name and password.

Tom offers to split internet costs with George, and George accepts.

Tom then runs an ethernet cord from the ethernet switch, out of his house, into George's house, and plugs it into George's router. Voila, two Wi-Fi networks, one Comcast internet subscription.

George is now up late at night, because he doesn't quite trust Tom.

**Question**

Is Tom able to access George's data if he connects to the ethernet switch? In other words, is this arrangement a security risk for George?

Underlying more technical question: **can one access data from a Wi-Fi network from the modem?**

**Aside**

Originally posted in Network Engineering [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/63078/56477), was instructed to re-ask in Super User.

Comment: no, george cannot get to tom's network, unless he specifically opens ports. george could replace the router with a hub though, but baring that, the built-in firewall will treat tom's network as untrusted internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would already appear that the two systems are on two different subnets. So simply trying to browse will not work, but access by IP address can work. Not hard to do.

Tom would need more commercial gear to set up a VLAN for better security.

Simpler: Tom can keep computers logged off and have very secure passwords. Phones are more trouble because you would need to disconnect phone WiFi if highly concerned.

*can one access data from a Wi-Fi network from the modem?*   Not readily. You need a router for this. If the modem has a router built in, then it can be done.

Comment: Hi @John, I edited the question a bit to make it more towards how the network is set up.  If the routers are both connected to an ethernet switch, can one access data from a Wi-Fi network from an upstream ethernet switch?